# C++ calculate sum of integers excluding multiples of 3

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop, modulus

I'm stumped on a VERY frustrating problem. Trying to code out a prompt to input an integer and output the sum of integers between 1 and the number entered while excluding multiples of 3 during the sum. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what my code is currently:

```
int v;
int q;
int sum = 0;

cout << "Enter an integer: ";

cin >> v;

for (q = 1; q < v; q++) {
  if (v % 3 == 0)
    continue;
  else
    sum = sum + v;
}

cout << "The sum of integers: "<< sum << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Please describe which problem you are having.

Comment: Be specific.  What does your program do that you don't like?  What do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Look at `if (v % 3 == 0)` -- you're checking that every time through the loop, but why would `v` ever change? And is `v` the thing you want added to the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your loop should be

```
for ( q = 1; q < v; q++ )
    if ( q % 3 != 0 )
        sum += q;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are adding `v` to sum, instead of the number that is increasing in the for loop, `q`:

```
for (q = 1; q < v; q++) {
sum += (q%3 == 0 ? 0 : q);
}
```

Also, you can define all your integers in one line, like so:

```
int v, q, sum=0;
```

Also, whether it's intended or not, the value of `q` is never added to sum. To fix, change the expression in your for loop to:

```
q <= v;
```